# SAS hex decoder

Tags: matlab, sas

The following is a matlab function that I need to convert to SAS. The 1st line for 'value' is shown below as 'SUBID_IN_HEX'.

```
DATA WORK.QUERY_FOR_GETS_DW_EOA_FAULTS;
    SET WORK.QUERY_FOR_GETS_DW_EOA_FAULTS;
    SUBID_IN_HEX = SUBID ;
    FORMAT SUBID_IN_HEX $hex.;

RUN;
```

'mask' and 'start_bit_pos' are arrays that consist of 9 elements. I'm new to sas and I would appreciate some good advice as to how to proceed.

Best regards,
Steve

```
function decode = get_TABS_bitpack_decoded(hex)

value = hex2dec(hex);
mask = [1 2 4 8 16 hex2dec('1fe0') hex2dec('fe000') hex2dec('3f00000') ...
    hex2dec('fc000000')]; 
start_bit_pos = [0:5 13 20 26];
for i = 1:length(mask)
    temp(i) = bitand(mask(i),value);
    decode(i) = bitshift(temp(i),-start_bit_pos(i));
end
decode = decode(:);
```

I have an updated code version below. I get an error 124 following the array decod{9}. The commented portion shows a brute force method that illustrates the concept. The do-loop is the ultimate goal.

Again, thanks for the helpful comments.

```
%macro decoderloop(SUBID_IN_HEX);
    call missing(decod);
    array mask{9} (1 2 4 8 16 8160 1040384 66060288 4227858432);
    array start_bit_pos{9} (0:5 13 20 26);
    array decod{9} (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0);

    /*

    temp = band(mask[1],SUBID_IN_HEX);
    decod[1] = BRSHIFT(temp,start_bit_pos[1]);
    temp = band(mask[2],SUBID_IN_HEX);
    decod[2] = BRSHIFT(temp,start_bit_pos[2]);
    temp = band(mask[3],SUBID_IN_HEX);
    decod[3] = BRSHIFT(temp,start_bit_pos[3]);
    temp = band(mask[4],SUBID_IN_HEX);
    decod[4] = BRSHIFT(temp,start_bit_pos[4]);
    temp = band(mask[5],SUBID_IN_HEX);
    decod[5] = BRSHIFT(temp,start_bit_pos[5]);
    temp = band(mask[6],SUBID_IN_HEX);
    decod[6] = BRSHIFT(temp,start_bit_pos[6]);
    temp = band(mask[7],SUBID_IN_HEX);
    decod[7] = BRSHIFT(temp,start_bit_pos[7]);
    temp = band(mask[8],SUBID_IN_HEX);
    decod[8] = BRSHIFT(temp,start_bit_pos[8]);
    temp = band(mask[9],SUBID_IN_HEX);
    decod[9] = BRSHIFT(temp,start_bit_pos[9]);*/
    %do i = 1 %to 9;
        temp = band(mask[&i],SUBID_IN_HEX);
        decod[&i] = BRSHIFT(temp,start_bit_pos[&i]);
    %end;
%mend decoderloop;
```

Comment: Please could you post some sample inputs and expected outputs for your function?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  We're not a code writing service, you're welcome to hire a consultant for that if that's what you need.  If you want help here, you need to try and solve this yourself and ask specific questions that are answerable.  In particular, you probably need to work out what this is supposed to be doing, and then attempt it in SAS using SAS techniques; bit packing isn't a typical SAS technique, so there's probably a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

My Matlab is pretty rusty, but I believe the following does what you are looking for by creating a subroutine call get_TABS_bitpack_decoded which returns a horizontal array, which can be transposed in the receiving data step.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.func.conv;
    function hex2dec(hex $);
        return (inputn(hex,cats('hex',lengthn(hex),'.')));
    endsub;

    subroutine get_TABS_bitpack_decoded(hex $, out[9]);
        outargs out;
        value = hex2dec(hex);
        array mask[9] /nosymbols (1 2 4 8 16 1fe0x 0fe000x 3f00000x /*...*/ 0fc000000x);
        array start_bit_pos[9] /nosymbols (0 1 2 3 4 5 13 20 26);
        file log;
        do i=1 to dim(mask);
            temp=band(mask[i],value);
            out[i]=brshift(temp,start_bit_pos[i]);
        end;
    endsub;
quit;

options cmplib=work.func;

data work.query_for_gets_dw_eoa_faults;
    input subid @@;
    SUBID_IN_HEX = put(subid,hex16.);
    array _decode[9] _temporary_;
    call get_TABS_bitpack_decoded(SUBID_IN_HEX,_decode);
    do i=1 to dim(_decode);
      decode=_decode[i];
      output;
    end;
datalines;
8160
;
run;

proc print data=work.query_for_gets_dw_eoa_faults;
    id SUBID;
    var i decode;
run;
```

```
subid | i | decode
----- | - | ------
 8160 | 1 |      0
 8160 | 2 |      0
 8160 | 3 |      0
 8160 | 4 |      0
 8160 | 5 |      0
 8160 | 6 |    255
 8160 | 7 |      0 
 8160 | 8 |      0 
 8160 | 9 |      0
```

```
%macro decoderloop(var);
    *call missing(decod);*this here causes intantiation or decod as scalar not array;
    array mask[9]          _temporary_ (1 2 4 8 16 8160 1040384 66060288 4227858432);
    array start_bit_pos[9] _temporary_ (0:5 13 20 26);
    array decod[9];
    call pokelong(repeat(put(0,rb8.),8),addrlong(decod[1]),72);*initialize values of decod to all 0, replaces bad call missing and array defaults which do not reinitialize upon data step iteration;
    do _n_=1 to 9;*no macro loop, loop in data step instead of generating repeated code;
      decod[_n_]=brshift(band(mask[_n_],&var),start_bit_pos[_n_]);
    end;
%mend;
data foo;
    SUBID_IN_HEX=8160;
    %decoderloop(SUBID_IN_HEX)
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have an update sas code below. Commented out is a brute force method that shows the concept. The do loop is what I'd like to get to. However, I get error 124 following the array decod{9} line.

Comment: Hi Fried, I tested the macro decoderloop and it worked fine. Thanks so much for the help. - steve